# Multiple regression in R using CVlm

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a data frame of 51 columns where the 1st column is the response variable and all other columns are the predictor variables. I want to pass this data frame to the CVlm function in DAAG package, but I don't know how to write 50 columns in the formula's right hand side in a short way. Normally I would write all predictor column names with a plus (+) in between, as below if I had only 3 predictor variables:

```
CVlm(dataset, form.lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4))
```

But with 50 predictors, it does not make sense to list all of them like this. Is there a shorthand notation to do something as below:

```
CVlm(dataset, form.lm(V1 ~ V2...V50))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have to just add a `.` to include all variable in the dataset.

```
CVlm(dataset, form.lm(V1 ~ .))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time using linear regression in R, and I didn't read about this general simple usage anywhere before. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In addition with the answer of SabDeM, you can find interesting to have a look at several sources with information regarding the type of formulae in R.

For example, you can consider to review the first part of chapter 11 of "An introduction to R", which you can find at: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Also, a quick reference site can be the Tutorials by William B. King, which you can find at: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html

Best regards,

Pablo